# Sharing objects between two localStorage items

Tags: javascript, local-storage

At the moment I have two localStorage items storing arrays of objects that sum up to this, where `arr` is an array of objects unrelated to those in the items' arrays:

```
{
    name: 'foo',
    arr: []
}
```

Both items can have the same object in their objects' `arr`, but I don't want to duplicate each one shared between them to help avoid hitting the storage limit. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: That's not going to work, in local storage only strings (not string objects, but character sequences) are stored, similarly to cookies.

Comment: just store it in its own key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the md5 hash of `arr` content and store each `arr` in separate `localStorage` item and set the hash value as the value of `key` of that `localStorage` item. (Note the `md5` function is not a native one)

```
var key = md5(arr.toString());
localStorage.setItem(key, arr.toString());
```

now the object we will be storing will look like this:

```
{
  name: 'foo',
  arr: key   //note we are just storing a small key here
}
```

Now as the objects with the same content will have the same hash value, if happens you need to store an object with the same `arr` values, you will not use extra storage space.

Comment: I was looking to store individual objects in `arr`, not `arr` itself. This does work though